# OOP | Is there a way to call an inherited method using the parent sub-methods?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

Here is a PHP code snippet to illustrate my question:

```
<?php

class A {
    protected function subMethod() {
        return "A::subMethod";
    }

    public function mainMethod(){
        return 'calling ' . $this->subMethod();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected function subMethod() {
        return "B::subMethod";
    }
    
    public function caller(){
        var_dump ('Using $this.. '. $this->mainMethod());
        var_dump ('Using pareint.. '. parent::mainMethod());
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->caller();
```

Output (actual behavior):

```
"Using $this.. calling B::subMethod"
"Using pareint.. calling B::subMethod"
```

Desired behavior

```
"Using $this.. calling B::subMethod"
"Using pareint.. calling A::subMethod"
```

When using `parent::mainMethod()`, it's still using the `B::subMethod`, since `$this` in the `mainMethod` still references the object `$b` upon which the function was called. I know this is how it's supposed to work, but I don't see how I can use a parent method that depends on a parent sub-method without having to override the main method. I don't want to override it as I have many child classes and overriding the function means I'll have to add redundant code that is basically identical in the parent and child methods except for using `$this` instead of `parent::`.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I want to make sure I understand. You want `mainMethod()` to call `subMethod()` on A if it is called via `parent::` and call `subMethod()` on B if it is invoked normally via `$this`? I don't think this is possible. If you override `subMethod()` then the child class method is always going to be called and this is by design.

Comment: Thanks @siride! Do you know how to implement this correctly to achieve the desired behavior without having redundant code? (even if that involves refactoring the class structure)

Comment: It's a little bit difficult to give you a correct answer because I don't know your actual use case. But I would just have two `mainMethod()` functions -- one that calls `subMethod()` (which may be overridden by child classes) and one that doesn't. If there is significant code overlap, then you can factor that out into helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 simple ways:

1.
You might create a new instance of A in the caller:

```
public function caller(){
    var_dump ('Using $this.. '. $this->mainMethod());
    $newA = new A();
    var_dump ('Using parent.. '. $newA->mainMethod());
}
```

Then A doesn't is not extended and main Method would call subMethod of A.

---

2. 

You create a new instance of A in the Main Method of A under the condition, that a param is set.
Like in 1 A in the $newA instance is not extended by B will call the subMethod of A.

```
public function mainMethod(bool $forceA = false){
    if($forceA){
        $newA = new A();
        return $newA->subMethod();
    } else {
        return 'calling ' . $this->subMethod();
    }
}
```

---

3. 

Another way could be that you add a boolean param to the `subMethod` in B `$callParent` parameter and if it is true, then you call the `parent::subMethod`.

```
protected function subMethod(bool $callParent = false) {
    return $callParent?parent::subMethod():"B::subMethod";
}
```

B would be still called then, but B::subMethod would call A::subMethod directly, when $callParent is true.

Then you just pass through the `$callParent` param in the mainMethod:

```
public function mainMethod(bool $callParent = false){
    return 'calling ' . $this->subMethod($callParent);
}
```

For compatibility reasons you should add the param also to the subMethod of A and there it would be unused, for not creating an error in case the param is set while calling the subMethod of A. (That would happen if you would create an instance of A without being extended or the subClass would not contain the subMethod).

```
protected function subMethod(bool $callParent = false) {
    return "A::subMethod";
}
```

The Caller could look the same in solution 2 and 3.

```
public function caller(){
    var_dump ('Using $this.. '. $this->mainMethod());
    var_dump ('Using parent.. '. $this->mainMethod(true));
}
```

---

Lets celebrate this a bit more and use solution 3 as base.

In case something like D extends C, C extends B and B extends A comes into play, then it could get complex / confusing, when you would like to call B or something else in the middle and one class, lets say C doesn't contain `subMethod` but D does.

To be able to call something in the middle you would need to switch from a boolean to an integer and then just go the levels up.

```
public function mainMethod(int $callParentLevel = 0){
    return 'calling ' . $this->subMethod($callParentLevel);
}

protected function subMethod(int $callParentLevel = 0) {
    return $callParentLevel>=1?parent::subMethod($callParentLevel-1):"D::subMethod";
}
```

So far so good. looks simple.

Now you want to get results for D and B. That means two levels up right?

The caller in D now:

```
public function caller(){
    var_dump ('Using $this.. '. $this->mainMethod()); // As expectet, it gives you the D
    var_dump ('Using parent.. '. $this->mainMethod(2)); // Question: would you get the B job done, or is what you receive A...
}
```

Woops, what you receive is A, cause when C doen't contain `subMethod` like I wrote in the beginning of this part, then from D to B would be just 1. But when C would contain `subMethod` it would be correct. So this is a sidewalk where the pothoe of confusion just waits for you to fall in and drives your nuts.